# Filter list of available values after selecting a value LS2011

Tags: c#, filter, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, visual-studio-lightswitch

Is there a possibility to filter the available values on adding a new record? Please have a look at the following screen: 
 [image]
Each `MES_OPERATION` is assigned to a `MES_ROUTE` (both are foreign keys). Now i want to implement that after selecting a `MES_ROUTE` the list of `MES_OPERATIONS`s should only show the `MES_OPERATIONS`s which are assigned to that specific selected `MES_ROUTE`. 
Following a screen :
[image]
For your understanding: **after** selecting the route "*Daniel*" the selectbox of operation should only show the operations which are assigned to the route "*Daniel*".

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is called "nested" comboboxes, or "cascading" comboboxes. This can easily be done in a detail screen, but I'm not sure if it's possible in a grid (all my grids are read-only).

Have a look at these two articles, which will explain the technique, & you can see for yourself if it works for a grid.

[Nested AutoCompleteBox For Data Entry](http://dotnettim.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/lightswitch-nested-autocompletebox-for-data-entry/)

[Nested AutoCompleteBox for data Entry Part 2](http://dotnettim.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/lightswitch-nested-autocompletebox-for-data-entry-part-2/)

Answer (score -1):

Use ORM systems. If you want the simpliest way then use VS2010 and EntityFramework. It will automatically generate set of classes based on your database and map them. Entity Framework will recognize your PK and FK relations and create collection of Operations inside Route class. Then in code you can use something like this (sorry I don't know tables and database names).

```
var route = objectSet.Routes.Select(p=>p.Id=="some id").Single();
foreach (var operation in route.Operations)
{
//do your stuff
}
```

Also you can use other ORM for example NHiberanate. Here are some useful links to get you start:
[Simple NHibernate application.](http://www.packtpub.com/article/nhibernate-3-creating-sample-application)

[More detailed info about Fluent NHibernate.](http://marekblotny.blogspot.com/2009/02/fluent-nhbernate-and-collections.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that is definitely not the solution / answer i was looking for. I **need** a way to get this working in lightswitch - using nhibernate is not the solution to this problem. By the way: lightswitch is also using the entity framework - in my case in combination with an oracle database.